# Beginner crazy with - AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, root, toplevel

main.py

```
from window import *
from toplevel import *

w = Window("Title")
t = Top(w)
```

window.py

```
### IMPORT TKINTER
from tkinter import *

## CLASS Window

class Window():

def __init__(self , title):
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title(title)
    self.window.mainloop()
```

toplevel.py

```
### IMPORT 'TKINTER'
from tkinter import *

## CLASS TOP
class Top():

def __init__(self , master):
    self.top = Toplevel(master)
    self.top.transient(master)
    self.top.resizable(0 , 0)
    self.top.mainloop()
```

TOPLEVEL DOESN'T APPEAR AND WHEN I CLOSE "Window" THE CONSOLE OUTPUT IS: AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'tk'

SOMEBODY COULD HELP ME??  THANKS VERY MUCH

Comment: Use `t = Top(w.window)` instead of `t = Top(w)`. Or you can make `Window` inherit from `Tk`.

Comment: Just a helpful note - using `from module import *` for everything is a bad habit to get in to, especially when there's only one class/function being imported. Get into the habit of using namespaces - `window.Window()`, `toplevel.Top()`, etc.

Comment: Run `import this` sometime and read it. Then keep rereading it. I still do on occasion.

Comment: @MattDMo The Zen of Python isn't the best source for best practises. I don't understand most of it. I think it is better to just look over the source code of popular (more likely to follow best practises) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use widgets as the parent of other widgets. You're using `w` -- an instance of `Window` -- as the parent of the window created in `Top`.

You either need for `Window` to inherit from a tkinter widget (eg: `class Window(Tk)`) so that it is a widget, or you need to pass in `w.window` as the parent (eg: `t = Top(w.window)`)

Comment: YES!!!!  I WAS CONFUSED WITH TKINTER HIERARCHY.  THANK A LOT!!